# Reading in text file. Failure of while(file>>x) idiom?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse a text file of the form

```
     -1.209,      2
     -1.194,      4
     -1.179,      3
     -1.164,      5
********************************
     -1.209,      2
     -1.194,      4
     -1.179,      3
     -1.164,      5
********************************
...
```

where there are lines of asterixs between columns of numbers.

I currently have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    double x,y;
    char c;
    string tmp;

    while(inFile >> x >> c >> y){ // "standard" file reading idiom
        cout << x << " " << y << endl; //do processing
    }
    getline(inFile, tmp); // *** line
    cout << tmp << endl; //the *** line doesn't print. why?

    return 0;
}
```

Why can't I read the file after the while loop exits?

Comment: do `inFile.clear()`  after each failure to clear error flags. Stream in error state blocks all reading operations.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that! That works.

Comment: Are the `****` in unpredictable places?, if so it is not a failure of the failure but the fact that you have to contemplate the possibility that the line is not numeric. (you can cheat somewhat using `peek`).

Answer (score 1):

There is another common idiom that relies on loading a line at time.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    double x,y;
    char c;
    string tmp;
    while(getline(inFile, tmp) and (not tmp.empty()) and (not tmp[0]=='*')){
       std::istringstream iss(tmp);
       iss >> x >> c >> y;
       assert(iss);
       cout << x << " " << y << endl; //do processing
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah! That was the other way of doing it I was trying to get working,but didn't know enough words to search for. `istringstream` will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a completely different approach. I recommend to use C++ and the object oriented approach. Problems will be decomposed to smaller problems. And then we solve evrything from bottom up. That is in most cases simpler.

The reality will be abstracted from small to big.

And, important, use objects. Data and the methods operating on the data belong together. For example: Only the object, that holds the `double`and `int` value, should handle its data. Nobody else. With the big advantage that, if data should change, only the smallest part needs to be updated. The rest will continue to work, without the need of any modification.

So, let's define 3 objects, and each object will have the insert and extractor operator overloaded.

Then, after openeing the file, a simple extraction, e.g. `ifs >> data;` will read and parse all data. Output is similar easy: `std::cout << data;`.

Please see the below example, to understand, what I mean.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// Abstratcion of one line with values
struct LineData {
    // Data
    double d{};
    int i{};

    // Extraction operator. Read data with standard approach
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, LineData& d) {
        char c{};
        return is >> d.d >> c >> d.i;
    }
    // Simple insertion operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const LineData& d) {
        return os << d.d << '\t' << d.i << '\n';
    }
};

// Abstraction of one record. So, many lines with data, with a last line of stars as separator
struct Record {
    // Our data. All lines with the double and integer values
    std::vector<LineData> lineData{};

    // Extractor: Read all values and the last line with starts. Ignore blank lines.
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Record& r) {

        // Read data, until we hit the end of e record, denoted by stars
        for (bool readingRecord{ true }; readingRecord and is;) {

            // Read a complete line from the stream
            if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line))

                // Ignore empty kines
                if (not line.empty())

                    // In case of stars, stop reding line data for this record
                    if (line[0] == '*') readingRecord = false;
                    else {
                        // Put the already read line into a std::istringstream for further extraction
                        std::istringstream iss{ line };
                        LineData ld{};
                        // Call extractor from LineData and add this line data to the record, inc ase of success
                        if (iss >> ld) r.lineData.emplace_back(std::move(ld));
                    }
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Simple inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & os, const Record & r) {
        std::copy(r.lineData.begin(), r.lineData.end(), std::ostream_iterator<LineData>(os));
        return os << '\n';
    }
};
// Abstratcion of Data, of the complete file
struct Data {

    // Afile consists of records
    std::vector<Record> data{};

    // Simple extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Data& d) {

        // Read records until end of file
        for (Record r{}; is >> r; d.data.emplace_back(std::move(r)))
            ;
        return is;
    }
    // Simple inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Data& d) {
        std::copy(d.data.begin(), d.data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Record>(os));
        return os << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {

    // Her all data from the file will be stored
    Data data{};

    // Open file and and check, if it is open
    if (std::ifstream ifs{ "test.txt" }; ifs) {

        // Read complete file and parse it
        ifs >> data;

        // Show result
        std::cout << data;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is overkill for this current example, especially as I missed out the header information that is coming with each line of stars, but it is quite useful for the containers I want to write.

Comment: Although I think this is the correct approach in principle, the technique doesn’t scale unfortunately because you will end up writing a class for each little grammatical structure in your file. If you want to have a formal approach to the grammar of your file you could try using Boost.Spirit, which allow to define and use grammars in place.

Comment: I agree to both statements. This should only show the general idea. For a simple data struture like the above, I would probably use the shown approach. For more complex stuff, I would create a parser. But, because I am oldschool, and the simplicity of it, I would always implement a handcrafted  parser, with a simple grammar and a simple shift reduce parser. Sorry for that . . .